# Did I get the cards?

Tags: clash-royale

Today while playing clash royale, I opened a golden chest but I got disconnected. When I again opened the game, my golden chest was not there.

Did I get the cards that were in the chest?

If I did not get the cards, is there any way I can get that chest back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this happen before, and you do indeed get the cards.  You just won't know which cards you earned (unless you remember the number of each card you had before...).

It's happened to me multiple times, with crown chests, free chests, and win chests.  I can usually tell that I still got the rewards because of my gold (which I tend to remember) or my gems (in the case of crown/free chests).